# c# identity can't create custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

This is my class derived from IdentityUser:

```
    public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }
}
```

This is DbContext

```
public class SecurityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    private string connectionString;
    private string dbProvider;

    public SecurityDbContext(string connectionString, string dbProvider)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        this.dbProvider = dbProvider;
    }
```

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<SecurityDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dataContext")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SecurityDbContext>()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I added property Extension, deleted all tables and called

```
EnsureDatabasesCreated();
```

It created all tables, but AspNetUsers table does not contain Extension property. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of identity are you using

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity(2.1.1)

Comment: If all else fails just add the column manually to the database table.

Comment: Will I be able to use UserManager's methods with it? Currently, UserManager doesn't see this property.

Comment: Provided you have `UserManager<User>` it should see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to add this field to my RegisterRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to make your context inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` where `TUser` is your customized user type (`User` in the code that you provided) that also inherites from `IdentityUser`, like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
     {
     }
}
```

Is this a netcore webapp? If so, please ensure you've also registered Identity on your `ServiceProvider` and specified your custom User class, at the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     ...
     services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
         .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>();
     ...
 }
```

specifying your custom `User` class and  custom `Role` class if needed.

Comment: @Jamil edited the answer with `ServiceProvider` registration specifying User and Role classes, did you also did that?

Comment: Yes. All Identity-related tables are generated, I just need to add one custom property.

Comment: @Jamil, but ensure you're passing your user class to all the services calls.

Comment: I didn't get that. I already used Identity with default properties(UserName, etc.) and it worked fine.

Comment: I mean that when you register the ASP.Net Identity services on you `Startup.cs` use the method overload that allows you to specify the user class you're going to use. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Jamil I edited my anwser please consired adding the two adds (`UserManager<TUser>` and `SignManager<TUser>`)

Comment: I added UserManager, still I don't see that property. Maybe I am looking in a wrong place? Currently, I expect it to be in the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: It should be there, by the way are you dropping the whole database and then staring your application over?